# Return reference to last occurrence of value in a column?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I tried the solutions from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/206623/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-last-occurrence-of-a-value-in-an-array-in-excel) but couldn't get it to work.

If C1:C5 = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 }

And B1 = 1

How can I return a reference to the last value of B1 (`1`), in this case, "C3" on Google Sheets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns the row number of the last occurance:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(if(C1:C5=B1, Row(C1:C5))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works, as explained in an answer to the question you refer to:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(A1)-1+MATCH(B1,C1:C5,1),COLUMN(C1))
```

It returns `$C$3` for your example.